# Firebase Analytics: "select_content" events with "Content_type" value: (not set)

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, analytics, firebase-analytics

I'm logging events with this code:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, value);
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "my type");
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);
```

The problem is that in Firebase console I can see some (400) "my type" events but a lot (1200) of (not set) events.

Why are appearing a lot of (not set) events? I searched in all my project the use of `FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT` and I'm always setting a value for `FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE`.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set all the same parameters for each event. Parameters are not a sort of secondary category.

In this case, it seems that you are send other event which is not having `CONTENT_TYPE`.

I had the same problem. In my case, you can see two events, `item_view` and `item_name`. As you can see, both events have exactly same amount of event: 4139.

[image] [image]

I was used parameters as secondary category, that means I sent an event only with the `item_value` parameter and another event with only the `item_name` parameter. But it was a mistake. As a result, there are a lot of "not set" events.

Check your total count of each event. If it is same, this is the cause. You need to all same parameters for each of event.